# x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (25,)

Tags: python, tensorflow

[ 340
341         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 342             raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
343                              f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
344         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (25,)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvDYh.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you change the 2nd line

```py
N = epochs=10
```

with

```py
N = epochs=25
```